# Upload images using a Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, windows-phone

I am trying to give users the ability to upload images using a form on my windows app. The images should be uploaded using a ASP.net WebAPI to a SQL Server db. I have found a similar example but I am sure there should be a much simpler way of doing this.

The example I found was 
http://chriskoenig.net/2011/08/19/upload-files-from-windows-phone/

I am not sure how to use the example above to convert it to an object and store it into the db.

Also, if there isn't an easy way, I am open to options of uploading the images into an external photo site solution that has an API, for eg. Flickr

Thanks for having a look at this!

Comment: If you want to use external api for uploading file or image from windows phone, my suggestion is use App42 API's http://api.shephertz.com/cloudapidocs/guide/0.8.3/windows/fileupload_api.html#upload_file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out a way of using a model to store images quite easily to a database using WebAPI.

Please use the link below to refer to my other post
[Upload image using ASP.NET WebAPI using a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220876/upload-image-using-asp-net-webapi-using-a-model)